# I have changed my site from php to ASP? Now What to do with my Old URL's

Tags: php, asp.net, seo, indexing

Recently i have migrated my website from PHP (wordpress) to ASP. And now what to do with me old URL's as it got indexed in google and now showing 404 error. And i have migrated server also. Could some one help me in resolving the issue. Is it possible to redirect my old php url's to asp or is there any other way to do it. I have around 2500 url's.. Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it it possible to redirect your old php urls to your new asp.net urls.

You should check out the IIS Url Rewrite 2 plugin: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/737/url-rewrite-module-2/

You should set up rules, that result in a permanent redirect. In time google will crawl your old pages, get the permanent redirect response code and update its index.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of to achieve that -

If there is pattern - e.g. all URLs are in the format of `scriptname.php?id=xxx`
follow the instructions here at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

OR

What you should do is set up a 404 page where you can check what request URL is. For example, if a request is made to an old `url www.yourdomain.com/products.php?id=10` then show your 404 page where you'll check that if

```
//If URL == products.php
//Get ID of the product
//Redirect to products_new.asp?id=10 or whatever URL you require
```

Comment: The problem is that i can't set up a 404 page in the server. Because i have migrated the server also when transferring php to asp.net

Comment: You can't setup a 404 page then its not a *server's fault* !